# Qt::userRole in QComboBox and keep color

Tags: c++, qt

I have got QComboBox widget with colors to select.

Its look like
"Red (Icon)" "Red (text)"
"Green" "Green"
"Yellow" "Yellow"

First is icon with special color (the same as text presents), second is text.

Now i want to take this value to draw my table (where i insert data)

I try to make:

```
ui.comboBox->setItemData(0, Qt::red, Qt::UserRole);
```

And next take color from UserRole, but i cant to do that (compiler error!)

In the end i have to change text into colour :

```
if(text == "red")
   color = Qt::red;
else ...
```

But this is not amazing solution

**Edit:**

Error:

> error C2248: 'QVariant::QVariant' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'QVariant'

Combobox:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/mrIwZ9c.jpg]

[image]

And i want to get color which is select (there selected is RED) in ComboBox and draw background in QTableWidget (in special cell) in this color.

Comment: Please show the code that causes the mentioned compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Description available in the comments.

```
QPixmap px(15,15);//create pixmap,size choose yourself, by your taste
px.fill(QColor(Qt::red));//all pixmap will be red
QIcon icon(px);
ui->comboBox->addItem(icon,"Red");//set our icon

px.fill(QColor(Qt::blue));//use our pixmap again, but with another color
icon.addPixmap(px);       //use our icon again
ui->comboBox->addItem(icon,"Blue");

px.fill(QColor(Qt::green));
icon.addPixmap(px);
ui->comboBox->addItem(icon,"Green");
//and so on, do this procedure with other colors
```

This code works as you want (to prove that I add screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Why do you add Qt::UserRole as the UserData? Should be QColor(Qt::red) a.s.o.

Comment: But how to get this colour and put it to brush ?
`brush->setColor( QColor(ui.comboBox_colorselect->itemData(ui.comboBox_colorselect->currentIndex(),Qt::UserRole)) );` I try that but cant compile -> error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'QVariant' to 'QColor'

Comment: Oh, choosyg , exuse me, you are absolutely right. I didn't notice this mistake yesterday, I edit my answer. Thomas Banderas, currentIndex() don't return the color, it returns only index. But you know that 0 is Red color, 1 is Blue and so on, so use this knowledges. Try to use switch-case or if() and setColor to your brush. Something like if(currentIndex() == 1) brush->setColor(Qt::blue)

Comment: I try to push color to ItemData (of ComboBox) - and take it to QColor. It is possible without switch/if etc? `ui.comboBox_colorselect->setItemData(0, QColor(Qt::red), Qt::UserRole);` - and how to Take it back to QColor ?

Comment: See the documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#itemData  ItemData returns the data which have index, but your index(if you use my code) have icon(icon not a color) and text, so you free to decide ehat you want to use, index or text(I think that index is better)

Comment: Yes but i set item data by `ui.comboBox_colorselect->setItemData(0, QColor(Qt::red), Qt::UserRole);` This sets data QColor(Qt::red) for index=0 yes? And now i want to return it back (QColor) for current selected index. Do you know what i mean ?;p